# Haskell Stack: separate work and non-work configs?

Tags: haskell, configuration, haskell-stack

My `~/.stack/config.yml` contains a private package-index in addition to Hackage. This is for work. I'd like to manage this so work projects will use Hackage and the work-specific index, while non-work projects will just use Hackage.

Git recently added conditional includes (`includeIf`) to [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), which makes it possible to adjust configs based on the path to the repo. Does something like this exist for Haskell Stack, or is there some other solution I can reach for?

Comment: What about putting the configuration in your project specific stack.yaml instead?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I was actually running into this when running `stack new`, so I didn't have a project specific config yet. I suppose I could add work-specific config files to each work project. That seems like a lot of duplication so I was hoping to find another way.

Comment: Another option would be setting the `STACK_ROOT` environment variable to different paths depending on what index you want to use. There's no built-in feature to do something based on directories like you're asking.